# Is there a known custom Android ROM without apps bloating

Tags: cyanogenmod, custom-roms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

I am looking for a very scaled down version of Android similar to CyanogenMod but with much less apps. I think just the OS , a basic landing screen and App Store. Is anyone aware of such ROMs ?

Comment: What's the point?

Comment: There are quite a few custom ROMs out there. For older phones, look at YoshiGinger, which is basically what you're asking for in order to keep older phones running well.

Comment: @Richard : With all due respect, there can be a very very specific business requirement pertaining to the open source based OS and scaling it down for a specific purpose. So from a business requirement perspective there is a point.

Comment: @Moss: That sort of scenario is fairly well outside the purpose of this site. This site is primarily for helping users of Android devices.

Comment: From a business perspective I would never rely on a project that has disclaimers gladly stating that they don't care if your phone blows up. If that wouldn't be enough the people that release these light stuff are usually the 1337 kids. They debloat CM so they have more free RAM because the ROM is smaller. They developer tool of choice is WinRar. I wouldn't touch that stuff with a 10 foot stick, let alone install it on something that makes me money.

Comment: And what if the business perspective does not include selling anything to anybody in the consumer market. What if it is part of any internal RND requirements. I can agree to what to you said above but only if that pertained to selling something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ones I know of are [Android Open Source Project](http://source.android.com/)-based ROMs.

Clean as they can be, no pre-installed applications (bloatware), just a "pure" Android OS.

You may want to read this [Community wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16265).

Comment: "Where can I find a custom ROM that..." questions are considered shopping questions and are off-topic here. Please review the [FAQ]. I expect this question will be closed as a duplicate of the canonical question which Zuul has linked to.